# Fatal Error triggers Before WP_Error handler

Tags: plugin-development, fatal-error

I have this code :

```
// this will provoke a fatal error because "Grap" without last "h"
$graph = new CanvasGrap(300,100);
if ( is_wp_error($graph) ){ echo "is wp_error"; }
```

Situation :

1. the echo is never showed.
2. wordpress crash.

Goals :

1. How do I prevent that like a misspelling error crash wordpress?
2. Why the message it's not showed ?
3. How do I must code this specific situation to see my custom error message?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I prevent that like a misspelling error crash wordpress?
> 2. Why the message it's not showed ?
> 3. How do I must code this specific situation to see my custom error message?

1. Spell your code correctly, to be blunt.
2. Because spelling the class incorrectly caused a fatal error.
3. Is `CanvasGraph` written to specifically a `WP_Error` object under any circumstances? `is_wp_error()` is for manually passing error messages around. It's not for handling generic PHP errors.

Your code should be spelt correctly, it's that simple. You shouldn't be writing custom error messages just because you've made typos. That implies that you intend to ship code to users you haven't even bothered to check for typos. Those need to be fixed before you ever ship it to users.

In development the normal PHP errors that will display or be logged should be sufficient for catching these issues. Writing unit tests would be a way to automatically run through all your code if manual testing isn't feasible, but that's too large a topic for a single answer here. [This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/automated-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/) seems to provide a good introduction though.

The purpose of `WP_Error`, and `is_wp_error()` is for WordPress APIs, or those in your own theme/plugin, to be able to manually return error objects to developers that are using them so that they can handle them downstream. For example, if you tried to use `get_terms()` with an invalid taxonomy, it will return a `WP_Error` object, because that's a circumstance that the WordPress developers could anticipate. But if you simply misspell `get_terms()`, that's your mistake and you'll need to use PHP's fatal error message to catch the problem, either by checking the error log or running tests.

Comment: Misspelling in this example is a kind of fatal error used with the purpose of illustrate around real objects to introduce a topic. The topic is "Fatal Error triggers Before WP_Error handler". So, in this case it would a PHP error that is provoking the crash and not about wrongly implement wordpress API, that's why WP_Error don't catch it and then crash. An error this kind has to be catched with PHP methods, you say @Jacob ? Testing wordpress it self is not the primary objective, but catch errors that crash wordpress running Linux server.

Comment: `WP_Error` is not for catching PHP fatal errors, no. If you want to customise the way PHP errors are handled, you can use something like [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_set_error_handler.asp). If you want to ask more about that topic, it's not WordPress-specific, so you're better off asking on https://stackoverflow.com/